# Jet ski maintainance

Tags: engine

I have two old jet skis, one of which isn't working too well anymore. I'd like to learn how to fix it. I'd probably not be able to sell it for very much anyways. Are there any good books or resources on jet ski repair? I know this is not usually available at your typical community college.

Answer (score 3):

In general, I would dissuade you from just buying 'a book on how to fix jetskis' and reading it cover to cover. This would not only take a lot of your time, but also not give you the specific information you're in need of.

My first check would be for a Clymer/Haynes/Chilton's repair manual for your specific year and model of jetski. There are some available on this [site](http://www.procycle.us/manuals/manuals_watercraft.htm), and of course eBay and Amazon. These would give you much more detailed answers that apply to your specific brand and model, and not generic one-size fits all pseudo answers (4 stroke engines look and work very different than 2 stroke ones, for example).

If you can't find this, I would start googling for specific problems. Lack of power? Poor seals? Bent/damaged impellers? Hull repairs? What exactly are you trying to fix? Once you pick one of these areas to address, start searching for replacement parts or guides to address each area.

Answer (score -1):

I also have 4 old ski's, ranging from a 1980 Kawasaki 550 stand up to a 93 Sea Doo xp, that I purchased from a woman that never rode it. It's like brand new,my pride and joy,looking thru her receipts. I found she had some motor work done to increase compression. This ski is faster than 90% of them out there.and the hull design makes it a blast to ride.  Its like riding an old husky 450 two stroke.  Anyhow, I've done dirt bikes, snow mobiles, and now ski's. I don't care what any one says 2-strokes are temperamental bitch's. The oil you use, the mix, the richness or leaning of carbs are more important than the rest. 2-strokes run with low tolerances cold, let alone hot. The micro amount of time that your motor let's you know its not getting enough oil, your brain still thinks nothing's wrong yet.THAT FAST !!! YOUR ENGINES JUNK.

Look on the web...any question you have will be be answered. Just remember, when your motor runs like it's not getting enough fuel it also isn't getting enough oil. Also too much oil will make your motor run lean, this is cause there is oil taking place of gas volume...But I will always rather have 2 much than 2 little. Jet ski's are a pain to work on, so I spend the cash to protect my assets. Get yourself a compression tester to start off with. This will let you know what you got under the hood,so to speak. You want your compression to match on cylinders, or you already have issues.

Google dude, Google. Good luck. TSKI.